# Haskell load external txt file into list

Tags: haskell

Hello the following code is a wordfeud program. It allows you to search through a list of words matching a prefix, suffix, and some letters. My question is, instead of using the list at the bottom, I want to use a external text file containing the words and load it into the list. How do I go about doing this?

```
count :: String -> String -> Int
count _[] = 0
count [] _ = 0
count (x:xs) square
    |x `elem` square = 1 + count xs (delete x square)
    |otherwise = count xs square

check :: String -> String -> String -> String -> Bool
check prefix suffix word square
    | (length strippedWord) == (count strippedWord square) = True
    | otherwise = False
    where
        strippedWord = drop (length prefix) (take ((length word ) - (length suffix)) word)


wordfeud :: String -> String -> String -> [String]
wordfeud a b c = test1
    where
    test =["horse","chair","chairman","bag","house","mouse","dirt","sport"]

    test1 = [x| x <- test, a `isPrefixOf` x, b `isSuffixOf` x, check a b x c]
```

Comment: Two short hints regarding your code: 1. In Haskell function application has a stronger precedence than infix operators. That is, an expression like `length strippedWord == count strippedWord square` is equivalent to `(length strippedWord) == (count strippedWord square)`. 2. In the function `check` the result of the function is the value of the equality check. Therefore, you can replace the guard (the part with the vertical bars) by the equality check.

Comment: You mean I can replace the guard with just this line "length strippedWord == count strippedWord square = True" ?

Comment: Sorry for being not precise I meant you can use `check prefix suffix word square = length strippedWord == count strippedWord square`. That is, the result of an application of `check` is the result of the application of `==`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very simple, with help of the `lines` function (or `words`, when words are seperated by some other form of whitespace than line breaks):

```
-- Loads words from a text file into a list.
getWords :: FilePath -> IO [String]
getWords path = do contents <- readFile path
                   return (lines contents)
```

Furthermore, you'll probably have to read up on IO in Haskell (I recommend googling 'io haskell tutorial'), if you haven't done so already. You'll also need it to introduce interactivity into your program.

Comment: `words` is useful for any whitespace, `lines` is basically a form of words with narrower split parameter.  For example: `words "hi\n how \n are\n you" --> ["hi","how","are","you"]`.

Comment: @AardvarkSoup I can't get this to work. Do I just replace the `path` with the name of my textfile `"dictionary.txt"`? Also where do I place this piece of code, between `where` and `checkw = [x| x <- test`?

Comment: You should make `test` a parameter to your wordfeud-function. Then call it from within an IO-function that also uses `getWords` to read the file. You do have to read up on IO in Haskell first, though.